# cannot import java.text.* package in j2me , netbeans

Tags: java, java-me

I want to import the java.text package to do some parsing of dates but i cant find it.
Netbeans usually gives a suggestion but this time it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [Connected Limited Device Configuration (CLDC) 1.1](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.1/jsr139/index.html) and the [Mobile Information Device Profile (MIDP) 2.0](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118) specifications, it appears that the `java.text` package does not exist.

However, as [binary_runner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433403/cannot-import-java-text-package-in-j2me-netbeans/7433529#7433529) mentions, the [Connected Device Configuration (CDC) 1.1.2 specification](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/ref-impl/cdc1.1.2/jsr218/index.html) includes the [`java.text`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/ref-impl/cdc1.1.2/jsr218/java/text/package-frame.html) package.

Therefore, it appears, as binary_runner mentioned, that the ability to use the `java.text` package with [Java ME](http://download.oracle.com/javame/mobile.html) is going to very well be up to which profile is being used.

Answer (score 2):

What **profile ?** If I recall it well CLDC does not have java.text included, CDC does, although not the whole Java SE thing.